# Image compression for faster rendering of web page

Tags: node.js, mongodb, image

I have some images in MongoDB database which I am retrieving through an API.

I want to know what is the best way to store them in the database and how to do image compression to make web pages load faster without sacrificing quality of images?

All the images are near about 1MB in size.

Comment: Run your images through [tinyjpg](https://tinyjpg.com) if you intend to serve it over web.

Comment: See [Imagemin](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin) and plugins  [imagemin-pngquant](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-pngquant), [imagemin-mozjpeg](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-mozjpeg), [imagemin-svgo](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-svgo).

Alternatively there are many online services offering API
[https://kraken.io/](https://kraken.io/)
[https://shortpixel.com/](https://shortpixel.com/)
[https://webimageoptimization.com/api-optimizer](https://webimageoptimization.com/api-optimizer)